# pass image path to child component nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I cant seem to figure this out I have a child component that has an image as props like so..

```
<img :src="logo" alt="logo" />

//...

props: {
  logo: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}
```

then in the parent component I am doing

```
<ChildComponent :logo="’~/assets/images/logos/logo.svg’" />
```

but I get a 404 error in the console and my image is not shown, now I know the image path is correct because if I hardcode it, it works as intended??

Is there something I'm doing wrong??

Comment: look at browser console what is image url in element.

Comment: @Deda the url is `~/assets/images/logos/logo.svg`

Comment: that is not for sure shown in rendered dom, find an element with the select tool, in chrome: f12 then ctrl + shift + c, select element and see its properties.

Comment: @Deda that is definitely what it says.. have you ever used nuxtjs before?

Comment: tilde is not a valid symbol in path string, try with `./assets` or ../../ < back as much as it needed.

Comment: @Deda if I pass that exact same string with the tilde in the src directly it works, the tilde sign is a shorthand that nuxtjs uses, it only stops working when it’s passed from a parent component to a child component

Comment: @Deda https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/

Comment: `:logo="/images/logos/logo.svg'"`
or
`:logo="require('~/assets/images/logos/logo.svg')"`
or in child component
:src=`require(${props.logo})`

Comment: @Deda `:logo="require(''~/assets/images/logos/logo.svg")"` did the trick thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing a variable, just a String, so you don't need the : in :logo, try

```
<ChildComponent logo="’~/assets/images/logos/logo.svg’" />
```